# Something like Query on a collection

Tags: java, collections, filter, guava

I have a list of objects which have properties and those are translated as columns in my project. These properties are compound name, batch number and storage. I have a dropdown which allows the user to select any value between 1 to 5. The purpose of this dropdown is that it should give you (in case you selected 2) - 2 compounds per batch and per usage type.

I have been looking at Guava library but it doesnt seem to fit in. Anyone has any ideas how to do this. This needs to be done within the code itself so yeah, database is out of question.

Comment: Your question is really unclear.

Comment: Show us some code you tried and expected output.

Comment: Some explicit examples of input and desired results would help here.

Comment: While a database is out of the question, perhaps showing us the query you would use will clarify what you are trying to achieve without a database.

Comment: Ok so I have a list of objects which is tied to a table model. This list contains obj1, obj2, ob3 and so on....each object has a property such as batch number, compound number, usageType etc. Now I am throwing this list to a JTable. Now I have a dropdown selector and let's say I select 2. From this point on wards what should ideally happen is my list should get filtered in such a way that I have 2 compounds per batch and per usage type. Hope this makes it clear. Writing the code is not an issue... Is this even something that can be done just within the code?

Comment: I don't understand how this question does not make sense? All I am asking is to tell me how to map many values to one key. But anyways, I found the solution myself and it was through MultiMap.

Comment: @Bytekoder: For me your question makes sense, but it's quite unclear. You'd have better edited it, explanation in comments aren't that good. And I'm still unsure about what you need. First two elements of each type?

Comment: Well, yeah first two elements in this case. But it could be 3, 4, 5 as well if the user chooses to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to query collections in Java you can take a look at multiple alternative:

- [Quaere](http://quaere.codehaus.org/)

  > Quaere is an open source, extensible framework that adds a querying syntax reminiscent of SQL to Java applications. Quaere allows you to filter, enumerate and create projections over a number of collections and other queryable resources using a common, expressive syntax.
- [JXPath](http://commons.apache.org/jxpath/)

  > The org.apache.commons.jxpath package defines a simple interpreter of an expression language called XPath. JXPath applies XPath expressions to graphs of objects of all kinds: JavaBeans, Maps, Servlet contexts, DOM etc, including mixtures thereof.

Google Guava could certainly do what you want, there is also Op4J, Apache Common Collections with Filters/predicates but you will have to write your custom filters/methods.

Comment: Thanks Man! Apache Collections Commons saved me. I used the MultiMap on there and it exactly did what I wanted.